# Spring boot RequestMapping

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

При вызове метода getProfile в контроллере

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getProfile(ModelMap model){
        model.addAttribute("profile", true);
        return "/registration";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/profile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String profile(@Valid @ModelAttribute User newUser, ModelMap model){

        return "/registration";
    }

}
```

у меня возникает ошибка. Путь /users подставляется в начало WEB-INF

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Oct 15 20:13:39 MSK 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/users/WEB-INF/pages/registration.jsp
```

[image: путь к файлу registration.jsp]

файл находится в WEB-INF/pages/registration.jsp

**Как мне используя метод getProfile перейти правильно на registration.jsp?**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {


    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
```

`resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");`  // поставил в начале слеш и заработало

Answer (score 0):

Просто

```
return "registration";
```

`ViewResolver` подставит перед строкой возвращённой из контроллера то, что передано в `setPrefix`, добавит в конец то, что передано в `setSuffix`, и попытается открыть файл по получившемуся пути - `/WEB-INF/pages/registration.jsp`.